# Network type in Xamarin.iOS

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I am work in `Xamarin`. And now I want to get the current type of network in `Xamarin.iOS` .Such as `4G,3G,wifi`...

I am new in `Xamarin`. Any suggestion would be useful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get connected network type use `CTTelephonyNetworkInfo` class like this

```
var telephonyInfo = new CTTelephonyNetworkInfo();
var networkType = telephonyInfo.CurrentRadioAccessTechnology;
```

Possibles values defined which you will get are as follows : `CTRadioAccessTechnologyGPRS`, `CTRadioAccessTechnologyEdge` ,`CTRadioAccessTechnologyWCDMA` , `CTRadioAccessTechnologyLTE` etc

Answer (score 1):

You can grab this `Reachability` class which comes from an iOS sample: https://github.com/xamarin/ios-samples/blob/master/ReachabilitySample/reachability.cs

Then you can get the connection status with:

```
var internetStatus = Reachability.InternetConnectionStatus();
switch(internetStatus)
{
    case NetworkStatus.ReachableViaCarrierDataNetwork:
        // do something on cellular network
        break;
    case NetworkStatus.ReachableViaWiFiNetwork:
        // do something on wifi network
        break;
}
```

You can get notified for changes with:

```
Reachability.ReachabilityChanged += OnReachabilityChanged;

private void OnReachabilityChanged(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    internetStatus = Reachability.InternetConnectionStatus();
}
```