# Xamarin.Mac - Network connected / disconnected event

Tags: c#, cocoa, xamarin, xamarin.mac

How can I detect the internet connectivity in a **Xamarin.Mac** app? How can I **receive an event** when LAN cable is plugged / unplugged, WIFI connected / disconnected or connected to other available networks?

My application can only run on an internal network and I need to show the online / offline status i.e. online when on company network, offline when not on company network or no internet connection.

Comment: Refer here @Cheesebaron answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52200514/network-type-in-xamarin-ios/52201847#52201847

Answer (score 0):

Figured out below to help suffice my need

```
NetworkReachability _defaultRouteReachability;
public override void WindowDidLoad()
{
   if (_defaultRouteReachability == null)
   {
      _defaultRouteReachability = new NetworkReachability("https://example.com");
      _defaultRouteReachability.Schedule(CFRunLoop.Current, CFRunLoop.ModeDefault);
      _defaultRouteReachability.SetNotification(HandleNotification);
   }
}

void HandleNotification(NetworkReachabilityFlags flags)
{
   //Handle your actions here.
}
```