# how to determine if network type is 2g, 3g or 4g using xamarin essential

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, cross-platform

how can i determine if network type is 2g, 3g or 4g using xamarin essential

I know xamarin essential  has functions to identify connectivity type

```
var current = Connectivity.NetworkAccess;

if (current == NetworkAccess.Internet)
{
     // Connection to internet is available
}
```

But if it is internet type then i want to know if it is 2g/3g/4g/5g

Comment: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52201847/1875256

Answer (score 2):

Check Connectivity plugin 
https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/ConnectivityPlugin
and ConnectionTypes

```
public enum ConnectionType
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Cellular connection, 3G, Edge, 4G, LTE
    /// </summary>
    Cellular,
    /// <summary>
    /// Wifi connection
    /// </summary>
    WiFi,
    /// <summary>
    /// Desktop or ethernet connection
    /// </summary>
    Desktop,
    /// <summary>
    /// Wimax (only android)
    /// </summary>
    Wimax,
    /// <summary>
    /// Other type of connection
    /// </summary>
    Other,
    /// <summary>
    /// Bluetooth connection
    /// </summary>
    Bluetooth
}
```

Comment: Doesn't really give an answer whether the cellular type is 2G/3G/4G/5G